# Byte to integer in C#

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I am reading a row from a SQL Server table. One of the columns is of type tinyint.

I want to get the value into an int or int32 variable.

```
rdr.GetByte(j)
(byte) rdr.GetValue(j)
```

...seems to be the only way to retrieve the value. But how do I get the result into an `int` variable?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`int value = rdr.GetByte(j);`

An explicit cast is not required, because a `byte` to `int` is a widening conversion (no possibility of data loss).

Comment: P.S. This is an implicit cast `byte` to `int`

Comment: I should have been more specific.  That is what I have already tried.  I get a "Specified cast is not valid." exception.  I have also tried:

    int value = (int) rdr.GetByte(j) 
and
    int value = Convert.ToInt(rdrGetByte(j))

Comment: @jtb: It seems to me then that you're not getting the tinyint column with the index j. What's the exception stack trace? The error must happen inside `GetByte`.

Comment: I agree with @Jordao; it sounds like column `j` is not a `byte`. Try `int value = Convert.ToInt(rdr.GetValue(j));`

Answer (score 15):

See the documentation for [BitConverter.ToInt32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.toint32.aspx) (contains more examples):

```
byte[] bytes = { 0, 0, 0, 25 };

// If the system architecture is little-endian (that is, little end first),
// reverse the byte array.
if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
    Array.Reverse(bytes);

int i = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);
Console.WriteLine("int: {0}", i);
// Output: int: 25
```

Comment: The question is asking how to convert a single `byte` to an `int`. `BitConverter` deals with arrays of `byte`s, not single `byte`s.

Answer (score 6):

Assigning a `byte` to an `int` works:

```
int myInt = myByte;
```

But maybe you're getting an exception *inside* `IDataRecord.GetByte`, in which case you should check that the index you're using to access the data record really points to a `tinyint` column. You can check the type returned from `GetValue`. It should be a `byte` for a `tinyint` column.

```
Trace.Assert(rdr.GetValue(j).GetType() == typeof(byte));
```

Another option is to forego the fragile numeric index altogether:

```
int myInt = rdr.GetByte(rdr.GetOrdinal(TheNameOfTheTinyintColumn))
```

Answer (score 3):

Quick tidbit I ran into as a kind of corner case.  If you have an object type that is of type `System.Byte`, you can not directly cast to int.  You must first cast to a byte, then cast to an int.

```cs
public int Method(object myByte)
{
    // will throw a cast exception
    // var val = (int)myInt;

    // will not throw a cast exception
    var val = (int)((byte)myInt)
    return val;
}

Method((byte)1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Casting the byte to int should work just fine:

```
int myInt = (int) rdr.GetByte(j);
```

Since [C# supports implicit conversions from byte to int](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y5b434w4.aspx), you can alternatively just do this:

```
int myInt = rdr.GetByte(j);
```

Which one you choose is a matter of preference (whether you want to document the fact that a cast is taking place or not). Note that you will need the explicit cast if you want to use [type inference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx), or otherwise myInt will have the wrong type:

```
var myInt = (int) rdr.GetByte(j);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
(int)rdr.GetByte(j)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to Stephen Cleary's comment on the accepted answer, however I am required to specify the size of the int. This worked for me:

```
int value = Convert.ToInt32(rdr.GetValue(j));
```

(And it also provided backward compatibility with a database column using an int.)